# Is there a way to fetch DNS records, which include the original TTL value of the DNS record, with PHP?

Tags: php, dns, ttl

I have searched the PHP documentation, Google, and Stack Overflow for a way to fetch a DNS record with its original TTL and I am unable to find a solution.  My searches always seem to lead me back to the PHP function dns_get_record().

The [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dns-get-record.php#refsect1-function.dns-get-record-returnvalues) for the dns_get_record function states:

> "Time To Live" remaining for this record. This will not equal the record's original ttl, but will rather equal the original ttl minus whatever length of time has passed since the authoritative name server was queried.

Is there a way to fetch DNS records, which include their original TTL value, with PHP?

Comment: The "original"  TTL is the one given by the authoritative nameserver so you just have to query it instead of any recursive nameserver. What the PHP documentation tells you does not come from the PHP code for this function, it is just a feature of the DNS, and by default you will query a recursive nameserer, hence the modified TTL. But you may have an XY problem: why do you want the "original" TTL anyway? What are you attempting to do with it, and why isn't the answer from any recursive nameserver enough?

Comment: Fetch the domain's NS records, pick one, and query _that_. Unfortunately though PHP does not provide any DNS functionality other than using the OS's resolver which will not let you do this. So no, you can't do this in PHP. I've tried. I wound up writing most of a userland DNS client and then giving up.

Comment: Why do you want to do this anyway?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Thanks for the reply.  At work, my department queries DNS records for troubleshooting.  Knowing the actual TTL helps with the process.  At the moment, we rely heavily on MXToolbox to query those records.  I'm building an in-house tool so that we can move away from MXToolbox.

Comment: @Sammitch I'm building an in-house tool and would like the information to be as accurate as possible.

Comment: @Sammitch "PHP does not provide any DNS functionality other than using the OS's resolver " I sure hope there is good DNS library in PHP that allows to specify which nameservers to query...

Comment: @PatrickMevzek the general response I got was "why would you need that?", then I'd explain my use case and get a "oh. well good luck then.". So anyway I got fed up trying to format DNS packets properly and handle all the edge cases and I imagine so has everyone else.

Comment: @Sammitch First hit in a search: http://www.purplepixie.org/phpdns/usage_guide.php  you can specify the nameserver to query. I am sure there are other libraries with the same feature.

Answer (score 0):

In your case my suggestion would be to just write a simple form in front of a `dig` command. Let users specify a hostname, a record type, and [optionally] a nameserver, and simply pass the `dig` result back as-is. Eg:

```
function dig($hostname, $type, $ns=NULL) {
        exec(sprintf(
                'dig %s %s %s',
                escapeshellarg($hostname),
                escapeshellarg($type),
                is_null($ns) ? '' : escapeshellarg(sprintf('@%s', $ns))
        ), $result);
        return implode("\n", $result);
}
```

Comment: Do not shell out to dig, use a library to generate and parse DNS queries and responses directly from the script itselft. Besides that `dig` is for human consumption and absolutely not suitable to parsing.

Comment: To find out the TTL you have to parse the output;. You should NOT parse dig output, it is not fit for that.

Comment: Have you read OP's comments? He's building a DNS tool to replace MXtoolbox. I'm not suggesting this be parsed, which is why I said "passed back as-is". _Read._

Comment: Have you read OP's comments? He says "Knowing the actual TTL helps with the process." How do you get the TTL from the dig output in your code? By **parsing** the output.

Answer (score 0):

I believe @Patrick Mevzek's initial comment is an actual answer to my question.

> The "original" TTL is the one given by the authoritative nameserver so you just have to query it instead of any recursive nameserver.

Along with @Sammitch's comment:

> Unfortunately though PHP does not provide any DNS functionality other than using the OS's resolver which will not let you do this. So no, you can't do this in PHP.

Comment: As an alternative, while not 100% perfect, I found [NetDNS2](https://netdns2.com/).